# Accessibility testing: select element missing an associated label

Tags: forms, accessibility

To have a page be compliant with all government accessibility requirements, each form element should have a label.  However, we have a birth date picker with three dropdowns: Day, Month, and Year.  The visible label is simply "Birth Date".

[image]

Is there a way to:

1. Specify that a form element has no label?
2. Specify that a label is for multiple form elements?

Comment: Please remember to include relevant language and/or tool tags in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a label for a group using `<fieldset>` and `<legend>`, however, this does not mean you can omit the individual label. In your example, you could argue that the proximity to the other selects serve as a "visual label", so you can use the `title` attribute to label each of the individual components and a fieldset/legend for the group

In your instance, you also need to indicate that the * indicates a required field

Here is some markup

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Date of Birth* <span class="offscreen">required</span></legend>
    <select title="month">...</select>
    <select title="day">...</select>
    <select title="year">...</select>
    <button title="pick date" class="datepicker"></button>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Relevant WCAG 2.0 Technique is [H65: Using the title attribute to identify form controls when the label element cannot be used](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/H65.html). Works with `input[type="text"]` according to [Powermapper extensive tests](http://www.powermapper.com/tests/screen-readers/labelling/input-text-title.html)